# What is the state of Arduino pins when the arduino is unpowered?

Tags: pins, relay

I'm building a control box to provide logical control of power outlets.

I'm using a 4 channel 5V optically isolated relay system to control 4 separate outlets.

To use optical isolation you connect arduino +5V to the VCC line, and logic inputs to the 4 channels of the relay unit, and connect a separate +5V supply to run the coils of the relays.

To energize one of the relays, you pull that control line LOW. To de-energize the coil, you drive the line HIGH.

If I power on the relay but leave the Arduino unpowered, all the relay coils energize.

Do Arduino pins float when it is powered down, or are they grounded?

Could I wire a pullup resistor to the inputs? And how would I do that without losing optical isolation? If I connect my pullup resistors to the +5V for the relays, the relay's +5 is connected to the Arduino's logic lines. If I instead use the Arudino's +5 rail, then when the Arduino is powered down, it's +5V line is dead.

Comment: Did you remove the jumper between VCC to JD-VCC?

Comment: PS why do you want optical isolation? The relays already provide galvanic isolation.

Comment: Yes, I removed the jumper so the 2 +5v supplies are isolated.

Comment: connect the opto-isolator LED between two of the digital pins ..... if the pins float or if the pins are both the same level then the opto-isolator will not activate

Comment: You mean use one of the Arduino pins as the VCC for the Arduino, and the other as the logic input? Then use the pin connected to VCC as a power switch? I like it. It still doesn't protect the Arduino from +5 coming into it's logic lines while the Arduino is unpowered however.

Comment: would an nchannel fet between the logic's gnd and the AVR's gnd prevent the intrinsic pull-down? you can then use the fet as a "relay enable" by driving its gate high, or simply tying it to the AVR's VCC

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pins have input protection diodes that clamp the pins to Vcc and Gnd. If a pin gets to >VCC +0.5V the positive diode clamp conducts and Vcc is powered via the internal Vcc bus, and if a pin get to < -0.5V the negative diode clamp conducts.  With Vcc = 0V, the pin could act as if it were a low, but more generally folks see the chip acting like it was phantom powered and attempting to run code with perhaps unpredictable results.  That's why the datasheet says to not drive the pins when th chip is unpowered.  If the clamp current becomes too much, the diode can blow, and either just the one pin is impacted, or the whole chip dies and it will feel warm/hot to the touch when powered up.

So don't power up the relays without also powering up the Arduino.

Comment: the circuit is wired only to Arduino VCC and pin on the LED side of the optocoupler  https://i.stack.imgur.com/14WTN.jpg

Comment: Hmm, that doesn't seem like the Opto could be turning on its output transistor then. Some relay boards have a jumper that connects the VCCs together. If you measure pins 1 and 4, is 1 low and 4 high?

Comment: My goal is to **not** power the relay without powering the Arduino. However, it would be bad if the AC power is on and the relay's power supply is "lit" but the Arduino's power supply fails or the Arduino fails to power up. In that case my outlets would all be turned on.

Comment: I have my project built so I can plug a computer into the Arduino's USB, in which case it draws it's power from USB and the relay is powered from a separate supply.

Comment: That would work.  Or use a 5V wallwart into the USB connector to keep the Arduino powered, if you don't need PC connectivity all the time.

Comment: Right, but my question is, how do I handle the error case where there is power to the relay board and the AC source, but not to the Arduino? (Simple case: I forget to plug the USB cable into the Arduino. More serious case: The Arduino's power supply fails or the Arduino fails to start for some reason.)

Comment: I guess there's no good answer other than "Don't do that." I might need a power transistor (like an N-channel MOSFET on the relay power supply, with it's gate controlled by a logic line from the Arduino.

Comment: or a relay board with coil powered if signal is HIGH

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out my question was a bit of an X/Y problem. I wanted to know what the pins on the Arduino do when the board is unpowered, because I was feeding +5V into the VCC input on my relay board when the Arduino was unpowered, and having the relay control lines connected to Arduino pins.

If you remove the jumper on my relay board, it has a VCC line that ONLY powers the logic level inputs to the relay control optical isolators  and a JVCC line that drives the relay coils. (The VCC line might also power the optical isolators and the other CMOS circuitry on the board, I'm not sure.)

I have my Arduino wired to a USB input that is driven by a regulated AC power supply when it's running stand-alone, and from my computer when it's being programmed. Sometimes I forget to plug the AC powered USB cable into the Arduino when I switch to running it stand-alone off of AC, and in those cases the relay lines tend to energize when I don't want to, **and** I end up driving +5V into the Arduino's relay control GPIO lines, which is not a good idea.

The simple answer is to connect the +5V line from the Arduino to the VCC pin on the relay board. Then when the relay's JVCC is powered but the Arduino is not, the VCC line to the relay and the control lines to the relay are all unpowered, so the relay is off.

Duh.